# Entity split in two databases

Tags: entity-framework-4

I'm working on a project already started by several developers before me. One thing in particular bothers me is that they have single entity split in two databases.

Entity is called Tracker.

First database is called ConfigBase, and it has table named Trackers that has TrackerId along with it's attributes.

Second database is called StoreBase, and it also has table named Trackers, whose elements have matching TrackerId as it is in the first base.

Moreover, to have things even more complicated, when you access specific tracker in ConfigBase, you gain SQL server name and credentials that allow you to access it in StoreBase.

Now all this isn't too much complicated if you use plain old ADO.NET. But as my task is to raise entire solution to newest EF 4.3.1, I'm having troubles maintaining consistency of my entity. Half of things related to Tracker entity are in ConfigBase and the other half in StoreBase, and usually I have to get both to get some result.

Is there any solution to this that does not involve virtual merge on database level. I'm looking for a solution that can be done with Code First modelling.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry but that architecture makes no sense to me.  I can think of no reason to split a single Entity between two tables, to say nothing of two databases.  I would push hard to merge the databases, otherwise you'll have to write a whole layer to handle querying and merging the entities between databases.

Comment: Choose the right hammer for the job, I suppose for this legacy app EF could be suboptimal... Even code first is usually a bad idea if you are working with an existing database.

Comment: Architecture was built way before I got project to continue on, so there's no much options left for me :) Basically you just confirmed what I already concluded by myself, so thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no solution provided out of the box because EF itself is even not able to use more than one database per context. So you will either merge your databases or you will access each database separately (with separate Tracker entity per database) and merge data somehow in your application.

Comment: It's already merged in application, one context is always initialized, and the other one is dynamically created after by connectionstringbuilder. Was just wondering if there's more elegant way to do it :) Thank you anyway :)